# Please, explain me a solution to exercise 2.2.1 of "Compilers. Dragon book"

Tags: compiler-construction

The exercise and an appropriate solution is written here: https://github.com/fool2fish/dragon-book-exercise-answers/blob/34db00b33f727571d4f0f338147f1eeaf18712b3/ch02/2.2/2.2.md#221

The exercise states:

```
Consider the context-free grammar:

S -> S S + | S S * | a

1. Show how the string aa+a* can be generated by this grammar.
2. Construct a parse tree for this string.
3. What language does this grammar generate? Justify your answer.
```

I cannot understand what the author means under "how string ... can be generated by this grammar". I re-read the article but still couldn't get an idea what it is. I have troubles with understanding all the steps of building a parse tree and why there can be 3 child nodes

Comment: `S-> SS* -> Sa* -> SS+a* -> aa+a*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar means that you can turn any S into one of the 3 options. So to create aa+a*, you assume to start with a single S.

To this S you apply the 2nd rule which leaves you with SS*

Now to the most left S of this SS* you apply the first rule which leaves you with SS+S*

Now you apply the third rule to every S which leaves you with the desired word aa+a*